# How to change ASP.NET_SessionId cookies path in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I am trying to change the path of the ASP.NETSessionid cookies.

The code I have already tried is as below.

In Controller/Action

HttpCookie cookies = Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
 cookies.Path = "/path";

But the same is not getting changed at all.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: But why do you want to do this?

Comment: Right now we are having a single page on the whole website. That's why need to restrict to that folder only.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to set the cookie back to the response object:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(sessionCookie);
```

Although you likely want this tied to the cookie authentication (I assume you are using that), and you can configure it via the `CookiePath` property:

```cs
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            AuthenticationType = "ABC",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookiePath = "/",
            CookieName = "ABC",
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
               {
                  OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                  {
                     if (!IsAjaxRequest(ctx.Request))
                     {
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                     }
                 }
               }
        });
```

And an additional article on specifically changing different aspects of the cookies. You need to be changing the cookies through the cookie manager or else the cookie response value will just be updated by .NET again on the next request:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/

Creating your own cookie manager, and editing the cookie how you want

```cs
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
    // … Your preexisting options … 
    CookieManager = new CustomPathCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager())
});
```